# GEKKO dynamic optimization negative degrees of freedom

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, battery, gekko

I'm trying to use GEKKO for minimization of combined power load from charging vehicle batteries in discrete time.

Each vehicle has an energy demand ('dem' in vehicles_info dict) which should be met within its available time frame (from 'start' to 'end' in the vehicles_info dict)

There is also a constraint for the maximum power supply (Crate) to the battery based on SoC-level in each time step. Thus SoC and Crate is continously calculated as intermediates for each vehicle battery in every time step.

A solution is found with the vehicles in the vehicles_list below, but the degrees of freedom is -1255. I guess this could become an issue for convergence with bigger systems (=more vehicles and longer time periods)? I can't really tell how to fix this.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np

#################
# Vehicles info #
#################

# start = starting timestep for charging of vehicle
# end = ending timestep for charging of vehicle
# batt = vehicle battery size
# dem = vehicle energy demand
# start_soc = vehicle battery starting state-of-charge

vehicles_info = {1: {'start': 5, 'end':50, 'batt': 700.0, 'dem': 290.0, 'start_soc': 0.2,},
                 2: {'start': 20, 'end':80, 'batt': 650.0, 'dem': 255.0, 'start_soc':0.2},
                 3: {'start': 40, 'end':90, 'batt': 600.0, 'dem': 278.0, 'start_soc':0.27},
                 4: {'start': 50, 'end':350, 'batt': 600.0, 'dem': 450.0, 'start_soc':0.15},
                 5: {'start': 90, 'end':390, 'batt': 600.0, 'dem': 450.0, 'start_soc':0.15}}

##############################
# Charging curve (max Crate) #        
##############################

## Charging curve parameters
C_high=2.0
C_med=1.0
C_low=0.5

SoC_med=0.5
SoC_high=0.8

n1 = 100 # slope exponential functions

# Exopnential function: Crate = C_high - C_med/(1 + m.exp(-n1*(SoC-SoC_med))) - C_low/(1 + m.exp(-n1*(SoC-SoC_high)))

###################
# Time parameters #
###################

time_stepsize_min = 1 # minute
time_stepsize_h = time_stepsize_min/60 # hour
start_timestep = 0
end_timestep = 400


m = GEKKO()

# overall time frame
m.time = np.linspace(start_timestep,end_timestep,end_timestep+1)

# variables for optimization (charging power)
P = m.Array(m.Var,len(vehicles_info))

# add initial guess and lower bound for the variables
for i in range(len(P)):
    P[i].value = 0
    P[i].lower = 0

# "block" time intervals outside each vehicle's time frame
for i in range(len(P)):
    for j1 in range(1,vehicles_info[i+1]['start']):
        m.fix(P[i],val=0,pos=j1)
    for j2 in range(vehicles_info[i+1]['end'],end_timestep+1):
        m.fix(P[i],val=0,pos=j2)

# Intermediates
SoC = [m.Intermediate(m.integral(P[i]*time_stepsize_h)/vehicles_info[i+1]['batt']+vehicles_info[i+1]['start_soc']) for i in range(len(P))]
Crate = [m.Intermediate(C_high - C_med/(1 + m.exp(-n1*(SoC[i]-SoC_med))) - C_low/(1 + m.exp(-n1*(SoC[i]-SoC_high)))) for i in range(len(P))]

# fix energy demand at ending time for each vehicle
E_fin = [m.integral(P[i]*time_stepsize_h) for i in range(len(P))]

for i in range(len(P)):
    m.fix(E_fin[i],vehicles_info[i+1]['dem'],pos=vehicles_info[i+1]['end'])


## Equations
m.Equations(P[i]<=Crate[i]*vehicles_info[i+1]['batt'] for i in range(len(P)))

m.Minimize(np.sum(P,axis=0)**2)
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp=True)
```

And some result plots:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(10,15))

# plot power, soc and crate curves
for i in range(len(P)):
    ax[0].plot(m.time,P[i])
    ax[1].plot(m.time,SoC[i])
    ax[2].plot(m.time,Crate[i])

ax[0].set_title('Power curves')
ax[1].set_title('SoC curves')
ax[2].set_title('Crate curve')
```

Answer (score 0):

The degrees of freedom are calculated at the beginning of the problem before the solver calculates a solution and knows which constraints are active. As long as this constraint:

```py
m.Equations(P[i]<=Crate[i]*vehicles_info[i+1]['batt'] for i in range(len(P)))
```

is not at the boundary (`P[i]==Crate[i]*vehicles_...`) for every `i` and time point then the actual degrees of freedom may be positive. If the problem becomes infeasible due to too few degrees of freedom then an alternative form is to use a [slack variable](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/SlackVariables) that minimizes the infeasibility.

Comment: Ok, how are slack variables used in GEKKO? Do i need to implement new equations: `(P[i] - Crate*vehicles_info[i+1]['batt'] + slk[i] == 0 for i in range(len(P)))` and `(slk[i] > 0 for i in range...)`? This does not seem to work for me. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?